# Not able to add Context in toast

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am not able to add context in Toast.maketext, Please find screenshot for more detail
[image: Plese find Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListenee` does not extend `Context` and you cannot pass it as a parameter to the method that expectects `Context` ot it's subclass.
But, you can get the context of the `SeekBar` that has the listener (`seekBar.context`):

```
Toast.makeToast(seekBar.context, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the SeekBar param in the onProgressChanged method. SeekBar extends from a View and all views have context, so:

```
seekBar?.context.let { 
 // Your Toast 
}
```